# Server sent events using sseemitter taking more time to respond

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, push-notification, server-sent-events

I have a requirement to send notification from SQL database to the user as Server sent events in Spring Boot. I have used SseEmitter to implement this.

```
1) @GetMapping(value = "/v2/user/notifications/event",produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<SseEmitter> sendNotification(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") final String token) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Connection","keep-alive");
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        List<HttpStatus> httpStatuses = new ArrayList<>();
        httpStatuses.add(0, HttpStatus.OK);


        SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        Integer nextEventFireTime = appConfig.getConfiguration().getInteger("sse.nextEventFireTime");

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Constants.MAX_THREAD_POOL_SSE);

        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            try {
                service.sendNotification(sseEmitter, token);
            } catch (BaseException e) {
                httpStatuses.add(0, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                sseEmitter.completeWithError(e);
                scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
            }
        } , 0, nextEventFireTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(sseEmitter, headers, httpStatuses.get(0));
    }
```

*nextEventFireTime is configured as 15

```
2)@Override
    public synchronized void sendNotification(SseEmitter emitter, String token) throws BaseException {

        NotificationMetadata notificationMetadata =
                getUnreadNotificationCount(token);

        List<Notification2> notificationList;
        notificationList =
                getSseNotifications(token);

        SseEmitter.SseEventBuilder event = SseEmitter.event();

        NotificationResponse2 notificationResponse2 = new NotificationResponse2();
        notificationResponse2.setData(notificationList);
        notificationResponse2.setMetadata(notificationMetadata);

        event.name(Constants.SSE_EVENT_NAME).data(notificationResponse2)
                .build();
        try {
            emitter.send(event.reconnectTime(15000L));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BaseException("Failed to send notification event.. "+e.getMessage(), Constants.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR,
                    "sendNotification", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

The client is waiting for the response and it is taking close to 17 minutes when there is no data in db for notification but count query is fetching the data and when there is data then also it is taking 4-5 minutes to give the response.

I am using SseEmitter first time and when I debug the code at server is executed but the response is still pending.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Why is the method `synchronized `? also why recreate a `ScheduledExecutorService` you should better configure a `TaskScheduler` and reuse that (now you run the risk in creating a lot of threads which might actually slow things down). You are also rebuilding the event twice not sure why you are doing that either.

Comment: I have used synchronized because there is 2 query to get data and I want one thread to finish execution before other thread interrupts. I am not using Task Scheduler because SSE should transfer data only when one registration is done from a user and I am creating a event then doing build in the next line.

Comment: The result of the call to `build` is ignored hence that is event 1... Then you call `reconnectTime` which creates another event, hence you are creating multiple events. Also if you want it single threaded then why even bother making it async? Seems like a lot of work for absolutely no gain.